# HTACCESS file not working for Clean URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Folder where page.php resides:** `http://www.MySite.com/index/product-details/`

**URL:** `http://www.MySite.com/index/product-details/1276/Electric-Circuit-Breaker`

**item_id parameter:** `1276`

**item Title:** `Electric-Circuit-Breaker`

I just need page.php to read 1276 as item_id. This is my failed attempt at an htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ page.php?item_id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ page.php?item_id=$1
```

Please tell me where I'm going wrong. Htaccess file is in product-details/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the `.htaccess` file in question is on the folder `/root/index/product-details/` aka `http://www.MySite.com/index/product-details/`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /index/product-details/

RewriteRule ^index/product-details/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ page.php?item_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

It will capture the id only and internally redirect.

If the above doesn't work change the rule into:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ page.php?item_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: The htaccess file is actually in the same directory as page.php. (/index/product-details/). Sorry I forgot to mention that, I just edited original post.